# border-radius not respecting z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a heading tag that is being covered up by an adjacent div. I have set z-index properties on them and they are not working like I want them to. I notice that this happens when I use the border-radius property in tandem with other misc. css to cause the alignment of both DOM elements to cross over each other. But, they are crossing in what is the wrong order for what I need. Any ideas?

[Fiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms7Qr/)

```css
h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    background-color: #e5dbc2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    line-height: 70%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index:999;
}


.cover {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    background-color: #efe8d9;
    border-top: 5px solid #6e537f;
    margin-top: -7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to position the header - add `position: relative;` to the `<h2>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Ms7Qr/1/ (`z-index` doesn't apply to a statically positioned elements)

From the [Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index):

> Other stacking contexts are generated by any positioned element (including relatively positioned elements) having a computed value of 'z-index' other than 'auto'.

Comment: `<div style="position: absolute; border-radius:20px; z-index:100;"> <div style="position: fixed; z-index:10;">> </div> </div>`  the above code is an example of what i am trying here the fixed div element data is not working as expected in nexus device but remaining device it is working i am not able to solve this if i remove the border-radius every thing works as expected any idea for solving this for fixed postion instead of relative postion